# Angular 1.4.4 (Module/Component based structure) - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (http undefined)

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-boot, angularjs-directive

I am using angular 1.4.4 (module based architecture). Below is my file structure. I am trying to call rest API(written in spring-boot) from service class. However, I am getting the error in the TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.
[image]

This is my controller class

```
class ConfigurationController {
  /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($rootScope, ConfigurationService){

    Object.assign(this, {$rootScope, ConfigurationService});
        this.name = 'configuration';
        let vm = this;
        vm.scheduleTimePeriod = 12;
        vm.dataTTL=30;
    }

    loadData() {
        this.ConfigurationService.getAllAccessPoint().then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);} );
    }
}

export default ConfigurationController;
```

This is my service class

```
class ConfigurationService{

/*@ngInject*/
    constructor($rootScope, $http, Rest){
        Object.assign(this, ($rootScope, $http, Rest));
    }

    getAllAccessPoint()
     {
          //  return this.Rest.one('/accessPoint/list').getList();
         this.$http.get("/configuration")
         .then(function successCallback(response){
            $rootScope.configuration = response.data;
            console.log('load configuration data: ' + $rootScope.configuration);
         }, function errorCallback(response){
               console.log('Unable to perform get request');
         });
         return $rootScope.configuration;
     }
}

export default ConfigurationService
```

The error sounds to me like the service isn't getting the HTTP object correctly maybe its dependency is missing. But when i use it directly in the controller, things are working fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, It is angular 1.4.4

Comment: @swetanshkumar of course you can use classes with AngularJS. See ES6 AngularJS workflow

Comment: Did you define ConfigurationService as a service with angular module.service('ConfigurationService ', ConfigurationService )?

Comment: @Zooly then its better to shift to Angular 4 than working on Angular 1.4.4

Comment: @swetanshkumar Why do you say this? Maybe Dharita is working on an existing Angular 1.4.4 project, and can't go to a more recent Angular version.

Comment: @Zooly because for `http request` we can use angular 1 $http method itself. And that is what I think.

Comment: Yes, you are right @swetanshkumar, I am working on an on-going project which is using angular 1.4.4 and it's not possible to migrate to any other version of angular because the project is quite huge.

Comment: @GSSwain , Yes I did as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line in `ConfigurationService`

> Object.assign(this, ($rootScope, $http, Rest));

to

```
 Object.assign(this, {$rootScope, $http, Rest});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let configurationModule = angular.module('configuration', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'agGrid',
    'kendo.directives'
])
.config(/*@ngInject*/($stateProvider)=>{
    $stateProvider
        .state('configuration', {
            url: '/configuration',
            template: '<configuration></configuration>',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: 'Configuration'
            }
        });
})
.service('ConfigurationService', configurationService)
.directive('configuration', configurationComponent);
```

Comment: try this   .service('ConfigurationService', **C**onfigurationService)

Comment: @GSSwain, I have defined service as import configurationService from '../../services/configuration.service'; So it wont work unless I change the name in import too. Any doing that doesn't create any difference.

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer